# scala play reads parse nested json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

I'm using `implicit val reads` to map Json like:

```
{
   "id": 1
   "friends": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "since": ...
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "since": ...
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "since": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

to a case class

```
case class Response(id: Long, friend_ids: Seq[Long])
```

I can only make it work with an intermediate class that reflects the JSON `friends` structure. But I never use it in my app. Is there a way to write a `Reads[Response]` object so that my Response class would map directly to the JSON given?

Comment: something like `case class Response(id: Long, friends: Seq[Friend])`?

Comment: that will work, but I don't have and don't want to create `Friend` class. I only need their ids

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need simple Reads[Response] with explicit `Reads.seq()` for `friend_ids` such as

```
val r: Reads[Response] = (
  (__ \ "id").read[Long] and
    (__ \ "friends").read[Seq[Long]](Reads.seq((__ \ "id").read[Long]))
  )(Response.apply _)
```

and result will be:

```
r.reads(json)

scala> res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Response] = JsSuccess(Response(1,List(1, 2, 3)),)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way could be:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, _}


case class Response(id: Long, friend_ids: Seq[Friends])

object Response {

  implicit val userReads: Reads[Response] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "friends").read[Seq[Friends]]
    ) (Response.apply _)
}

case class Friends(id: Long, since: String)
object Friends {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Friends]
}
```

without the `case class Friends` I'm finding it harder to find a solution but will post if I can find one

> Edit: Added link for answer on Scala reedit

So, I wanted to understand a bit more about how to parse json to models, and decided to ask on Reedit. Received some pretty cool links, have a look:

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/4bz89a/how_to_correctly_parse_json_to_scala_case_class/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
@annotation.tailrec
def go(json: Seq[JsValue], parsed: Seq[Long]): JsResult[Seq[Long]] =
  json.headOption match {
    case Some(o @ JsObject(_)) => (o \ "id").validate[Long] match {
      case JsError(cause) => JsError(cause)
      case JsSuccess(id)  => go(json.tail, parsed :+ id)
    }
    case Some(js) => JsError(s"invalid friend JSON (expected JsObject): $js")
    case _ => JsSuccess(parsed) // nothing more to read (success)
  }

implicit val friendIdReader = Reads[Seq[Long]] {
  case JsArray(values) => go(values, Nil)
  case json => JsError(s"unexpected JSON: $json")
}

implicit val responseReader = Json.reads[Response]
// responseReader will use friendIdReader as Reads[Seq[Long]],
// for the property friend_ids
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! That probably will work, but I'd rather go with an utility class (e.g. `Friend`), if there is no easier way of doing it. And I suppose there is none.